# Need To Rank Account Based On Annual Revenue

Tags: batch

I have requirement where we need to rank the accounts based on it's Annual Revenue and that too using Apex Batch class.

I have written the class but rank is not getting populated correctly. Please find the code and outcome screenshot below.

```
public class AccountBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful
{
    //public static Integer count = 0;
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        return database.getQueryLocator('select id,name,phone,AnnualRevenue from Account where AnnualRevenue != null order By AnnualRevenue Desc ');
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> Scope)
    {
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        Integer count = 1;
        for(Account acc : Scope)   
        {
            acc.Rank__c = count;
            accList.add(acc);
            count++;
        }

        System.debug('count = ' + count);
        update accList;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        System.debug('Batch Execution Completed ::::');
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because every time your batch execute a fresh chunk of records the counter reset to 1.

So you need a global counter variable and maintain its state.

```
//first declare the vriable globally
global integer count = 1;

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> Scope)
{
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    for(Account acc : Scope)   
    {
        acc.Rank__c = count; //then use them in batch
        accList.add(acc);
        count++;
    }

    System.debug('count = ' + count);
    update accList;
}
```

[State Management In Batch Apex in Salesforce](http://salesforceapexcodecorner.blogspot.in/2011/08/state-management-in-batch-apex-in.html)

Comment: Thanks Tushar !!!
Your comment helped me to get out of this. I just have one doubt can't i use a static global variable(global static integer count = 1;) to maintain the state of the variable instead using database.stateful?

Comment: @RaviRanjan I don't think static variable will work but you can give it a try.  Also if this solve your problem then you can close this question.

Comment: Static variable doesn't help to maintain the state of count variable inside the execute method, because i guess the execute method reinitialize all the variables in every chunk of data processing not sure.